# Detect zoom on GMSMapView (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, google-maps-sdk-ios

How can I find if the user zoomed in/out on my mapView (GMSMapView)?

I want to do that if the zoom is bigger than 14 all the markers on the map will disappear and if it's smaller all the markers will reload.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code assumes that the view controller has a property of "markerArray" which holds all of the markers.

```
-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition*)position {
    int zoom= mapView.camera.zoom;
    if (zoom < 14) {
        [mapView_ clear];
    }
    else{
        [self displayAllMarkers];
    }
}


-(void) displayAllMarkers{
    for (BarObject *barMarker in markerArray){
        GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        marker.position = barMarker.location; //
        marker.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        marker.map = mapView_;
    }
 }
```

Comment: updated answer.  I tested it in my build and it works.   Let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I also searched for this answer over the summer, and here is what I found and ended up doing:

Create a category on MKMapView:
I named it MKMapView+ZoomLevel

.h

```
//  MKMapView+ZoomLevel.h
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface MKMapView (ZoomLevel)
- (int)currentZoomLevel;
@end
```

.m

```
//  MKMapView+ZoomLevel.m
#import "MKMapView+ZoomLevel.h"
#define MERCATOR_OFFSET 268435456
#define MERCATOR_RADIUS 85445659.44705395
#define MAX_GOOGLE_LEVELS 20
@implementation MKMapView (ZoomLevel)
- (int)currentZoomLevel
{
    CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta = self.region.span.longitudeDelta;
    CGFloat mapWidthInPixels = self.bounds.size.width*2;//2 is for retina display
    double zoomScale = longitudeDelta * MERCATOR_RADIUS * M_PI / (180.0 * mapWidthInPixels);
    double zoomer = MAX_GOOGLE_LEVELS - log2( zoomScale );
    if ( zoomer < 0 ) zoomer = 0;
    zoomer = round(zoomer);
    return (int)zoomer;
}
@end
```

Then in your view controller:

```
#import "MKMapView+ZoomLevel.h

// insert logic here
double zoomLevel = [self.mapView currentZoomLevel];
if (zoomLevel > 14 ) {
  // add code to hide or resize your annotations
    for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapView.annotations) {
        if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
             [self.mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need for Google Maps SDK for iOS (GMSMapVIew) and not for mapKit (MKMapView)

Comment: Sorry about that, misread the question.   I added a new answer for google sdk.   It should get you going in the right direction.   I can add more sample code or link you to my project when I get home.